# How not to pollute domain model with persistence layer artifacts when practicing DDD in Golang?

Tags: go, domain-driven-design

I'm practicing DDD using Golang and do not want to pollute my model with persistence artifacts like bson tags, neither with json tags that has to do with encoding/decoding data coming from endpoints.

What is an elegant way of achieving that without having to define structs in three places?

I have gotten as far as to embed my model in a persistence layer version of my model, which wraps the model and adds a mongo-specific ID field, but the embedding means that i have to put my mongo tags in my model definitions and I'm faced with the same problem for my structs for enc/dec of my endpoints.

Comment: i guess you could create an api boundary between the domain objects and the persistence layer, so your unmarshalling code would use the tagged struct then invoke `NewDomainObject(unmarshalled.X...)`
BTW, why do you care? the tagged struct still represents the model, and can be used outside of a persistence layer. You may be trying to optimize something that's not broken simply to obey a pattern

Comment: @Plato good point.  it's a silly question really since the mapping has to happen somewhere and the domain model is a good place.  i started this whole train of thought by not being happy with having an id of type bson.MongoID in my domain models and then went too far with it, not thinking too clearly.  cheers for helping me clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is true, and mentioned in Clean Architecture.
You don't want to pollute your domain model with frameworks since they are your implementation details, not the core of your application.

I recommend you can try to place your object relationship into [the four layers of Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), and the problem of polluting domain model will become obvious.

To fix your problem, you can design data objects, which get exactly the same data as your entities, but not the behaviors. The annotations can be placed in these data objects, no matter whether you are using mongo or RDB in Go, Java, or any other programming language.
The only thing you need to do is to convert the data between your entities and data object while reading/writing the data from/to the database.

By doing so, you can find your application works properly with the database, while not polluting your domain model.